# The right place to call .removeObserver for NSNotificationCenter = Swift deinit()?

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, viewdidunload

I've read a lot of suggestions for the right place to call .removeObserver for NSNotificationCenter since viewDidUnload is not an option.

I was just wondering if the new deinit() in Swift would be a good choice?

-nick

Comment: viewDidUnload was never an option. When do you add the observer?

Comment: Not sure about that either. My gut says viewDidLoad, but some seem to think pairing viewWillAppear for adding and viewWillDisappear for removing. Others have stated that dealloc would be a good place for removing. I just thought removing in deinit() as the class is killed  might be a good choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It really depends on the role of the class where you subscribe to NSNotificationCenter notifications. If you are subscribing in:

**UIView**

Then you should unsubscribe as soon as view gets invisible to the user. To save CPU cycles and not consume resources while user does not see the view.

**UIViewController**

Here it also depends on kind of action that you are going to perform in response to notification. If it is just a UI adjustment that you should unsubscribe as soon as view controller disappears from the screen.

**You App Service layer**

Here it is OK to have `.removeObserver` inside deinit(). however even here I tend to suggest you to be more explicit about when you subscribe and unsubscribe from `NSNotificationCenter`notifications and put them in start and stop methods of your service.

Comment: Thanks Keenie. That does help. I'm just observing a text field in a view controller, so I guess the viewwillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods are the right choice anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

If you were previously calling `removeObserver` in `viewDidUnload`/`dealloc`/`deinit`, then starting with iOS 9.0 and macOS 10.11, you don't need to call it anymore:

> If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method.

source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver